# Calculating cumulative distribution of two samples

Tags: scipy, statistics, cdf, goodness-of-fit, cumulative-frequency

I was going through the a scipy code for [ks test (2 sample)](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3966) which calculates the maximum distance between CDF's of any two given samples. code for calculating the cumulative Distribution Function`(CDF)`.

I fail to understand the logic in the lines for calculating cdf. First, `data1` and `data2` is sorted and then using `np.searchsorted` we are trying to find the position of `data_all` in both `data1` and `data2`. `data_all` is nothing but concatenation of sorted `data1` and `data2`.

What if, the min value of `data2` is below `data1`. Doesn't that violate the assumption that `cdf` shouldn't be decreasing with value

```
data_all = np.concatenate([data1,data2])
cdf1 = np.searchsorted(data1,data_all,side='right')/(1.0*n1)
cdf2 = (np.searchsorted(data2,data_all,side='right'))/(1.0*n2)
```

Comment: Do you have a link for the example code you are referring to?

Comment: Hi. The test has hyper-link, which takes you to the code

Answer (score 1):

It's true that `data_all` is not sorted in general, but this does not matter for the computation.

- The array `cdf1` holds the values of the CDF of the first sample, computed at each of the points `data_all`
- The array `cdf2` holds the values of the CDF of the second sample, computed at each of the points `data_all`

Then the code does

```
np.max(np.absolute(cdf1 - cdf2))
```

taking the maximum of the differences of these. When you find the maximum of numbers, it does not matter in what order you look at them.

So, the order of these two arrays does not matter, as long as it's *consistent*: `cdf1[42]` is the value of CDF1 at some point and `cdf2[42]` is the value of CDF2 **at the same point**.

Comment: While computing maximum absolute difference of cdf1 and cdf2 difference, if there is some intersection b/w the modes of histograms of data1 and data2, wouldn't that affect the final score value(the maximum difference)